# Excel filter table values by multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables:

- one that contains a set of properties: their unique ID, offer type and reference points (for localization) - named Table_Prop
- one that contains requests from clients, that are searching for a property: their unique ID, offer type and the reference points they are interested in. - named Table_Req

PROPERTIES TABLE

```
Property ID Offer type  Reference points
      P1        sell        RP1, RP2, RP3
      P2        sell        RP1, RP4
      P3        rent        RP5
      P4        rent        RP5, RP6
      P5        sell        RP3, RP2
```

REQUESTS TABLE

```
Request ID  Offer type  Reference point
    R1         sell          RP1
    R2         rent          RP6
    R3         sell          RP3
```

All I want is to filter for each request the ID of the matching properties. So I did with this formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Table_Prop[Property ID],
(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Tabel_Req[@[Offer type]], Table_Prop[Offer type], 1))=TRUE)*
(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Tabel_Req[@[Reference point]], Table_Prop[Reference points]))=TRUE), "NO MATCHES"))
```

This works just fine, for each requests, it returns:

```
R1: P1      P2
R2: P4
R3: P1      P5
```

but 1 client has one or more reference points he is interested in, so the requests table would look like this:

```
Request ID  Offer type  Reference points
    R1         sell          RP1, RP2
    R2         rent          RP6, RP3
    R3         sell          RP3, RP4
```

Basically, now, I need a formula that returns all the matching ID Properties that has one of the request's reference points included in the property's reference points.

It should return this:

```
R1: P1       P2        P5
R2: P4
R3: P1       P2        P5
```

I found this formula that splits the cell value by "," separator:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(Tabel_Req[@[Reference points]],",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")
```

and I tried this formula:

```
=FILTER(Table_Prop[Property ID], OR(COUNTIF(Table_Prop[@Reference points], "*"&FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(Tabel_Req[@[Reference points]],",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")&"*"))=TRUE, "NO MATCHES")
```

but as I expected, it doesn't work.

How can I reach my goal, are there any workarounds? Any help is appreciated.

Note: I wouldn't like to use VBA, just a formula in a cell that returns a list of matching properties.

Comment: Because, it filters based on offer type too, R2 has "rent", therefore just P4 matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following is helpfull:

[image]

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(G2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A$2:A$6,MMULT(ISNUMBER(FIND(", "&TRANSPOSE(X)&", ",", "&C$2:C$6&", "))*(B$2:B$6=F2),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X),,,0)))))
```

Let me try and explain the (thought)proces:

- `FILTERXML()` will first "split" the reference points (input) into an array. For more information on how that works, I'd like to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) older post.
- In the 2nd step (proces) we will use a known series of functions to test if strings do hold specific substring; `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())`. The elements fo the previous returned array get leading/trailing comma's and will be multiplied against the result of comparing the Offer type.
- `MMULT()` will then generate a running total of each of the options under 'Reference Poinst'.
- The final result (as visualized in the image below) is input for the 2nd parameter under `FILTER()` and thus returning only those ID's of interest.

[image]

Comment: There are times that I am amazed by your processes.  I am definitely feeling like the old man stuck with his old tool bag complaining about how things were done when he was younger.